# Is there a way to get meta values from different levels using json_normalize

Tags: python, json, pandas, list, dataframe

My Json:

```
[
   {
      "totalCount":3,
      "nextPageKey":"None",
      "resolution":"7d",
      "result":[
         {
            "metricId":"gpuMemory",
            "data":[
               {
                  "dimensions":[
                     
                  ],
                  "dimensionMap":{
                     
                  },
                  "timestamps":[
                     1646006400000
                  ],
                  "values":[
                     17.68964385986328
                  ]
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "metricId":"virtualmemory",
            "data":[
               {
                  "dimensions":[
                     
                  ],
                  "dimensionMap":{
                     
                  },
                  "timestamps":[
                     1646006400000
                  ],
                  "values":[
                     65902238743.99306
                  ]
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "metricId":"ramUsage",
            "data":[
               {
                  "dimensions":[
                     
                  ],
                  "dimensionMap":{
                     
                  },
                  "timestamps":[
                     1646006400000
                  ],
                  "values":[
                     64.03194046020508
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "totalCount":3,
      "nextPageKey":"None",
      "resolution":"7d",
      "result":[
         {
            "metricId":"gpuMemory",
            "data":[
               {
                  "dimensions":[
                     
                  ],
                  "dimensionMap":{
                     
                  },
                  "timestamps":[
                     1646006400000
                  ],
                  "values":[
                     32.305381774902344
                  ]
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "metricId":"virtualmemory",
            "data":[
               {
                  "dimensions":[
                     
                  ],
                  "dimensionMap":{
                     
                  },
                  "timestamps":[
                     1646006400000
                  ],
                  "values":[
                     33188585566.78739
                  ]
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "metricId":"ramUsage",
            "data":[
               {
                  "dimensions":[
                     
                  ],
                  "dimensionMap":{
                     
                  },
                  "timestamps":[
                     1646006400000
                  ],
                  "values":[
                     18.978370666503906
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "totalCount":3,
      "nextPageKey":"None",
      "resolution":"7d",
      "result":[
         {
            "metricId":"gpuMemory",
            "data":[
               {
                  "dimensions":[
                     
                  ],
                  "dimensionMap":{
                     
                  },
                  "timestamps":[
                     1646006400000
                  ],
                  "values":[
                     99.68964385986328
                  ]
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "metricId":"virtualmemory",
            "data":[
               {
                  "dimensions":[
                     
                  ],
                  "dimensionMap":{
                     
                  },
                  "timestamps":[
                     1646006400000
                  ],
                  "values":[
                     99902238743.99306
                  ]
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "metricId":"ramUsage",
            "data":[
               {
                  "dimensions":[
                     
                  ],
                  "dimensionMap":{
                     
                  },
                  "timestamps":[
                     1646006400000
                  ],
                  "values":[
                     99.03194046020508
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

My Code:

```
#entitieisID is just the id of a computer
contentsList = (list)
for i in entitiesId:
                        api_url = '****'
                        config= {
                                "metricSelector": "gpuMemory,virtualMemory,ramUsage",
                                "resolution": "21h",
                                "entitySelector": 'entityId("'+ i+'")'
                                }
                        result = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers, params=config);
                        contentsList.append(result .json())
                #print(contentsList)
                s1 = json.dumps(contentsList)
                d2 = json.loads(s1)

                for d in d2:
                        df = (pd.json_normalize(d['result'],
                                                record_path=["data",["values"]],
                                                meta="metricId")
                              .set_index("metricId")
                              .T
                              .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
                              )
```

What i'm gettting:

|  | gpuMemory | virtualMemory | ramUsage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| HOSTID3 | 99.68964385986328 | 99902238743.99306 | 99.03194046020508 |

What I want:

|  | gpuMemory | virtualMemory | ramUsage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| HOSTID1 | 17.68964385986328 | 65902238743.99306 | 64.03194046020508 |
| HOSTID2 | 32.305381774902344 | 33188585566.78739 | 18.978370666503906 |
| HOSTID3 | 99.68964385986328 | 99902238743.99306 | 99.03194046020508 |

Any help would be appreciated <3

Comment: you only get the last `df` because in you inner-most for-loop you keep overwriting `df` with the latest one. You didn't store them up. try using a list to store each of them, and do `pd.concat(your_list)` at last

Comment: Amazing! pd.concat worked. My first column should be coming from a variable called entitiesId. At the moment it just shows 0. Is there a way i can get the first column to equal my variable e.g HOSTID1, HOSTID2 etc?

Comment: perhaps add `df['entitiesId'] = entitiesId` before you store `df` into the list?

Comment: No luck with this one unfortunately: ValueError: Length of values (3) does not match length of index (1)

Code:

```
df['entitiesId'] = entitiesId
dfList.append(df)
```

Comment: that should be ` df['entitiesId'] = i `

Comment: Gotcha, that worked, only issue is its only displaying the last value on my variable so all my rows have the last value of i so they're all the same

Comment: can you update your code in the question, and with proper indentation please?

Comment: I got it working, it was my fault. Thank you so Much Raymond, you're a star!

Comment: You are welcome! Good day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pd.concat(your_list)

worked

Thank you Raymond Kwok